# window.onblur event also triggers window.onfocus event when using IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Both the events are getting fired at the time onblur event.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"
Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onfocus = function() {
            $('#msg').html($('#msg').html() + '<br/> focus');
        };
        window.onblur = function() {
            $('#msg').html($('#msg').html() + '<br/> Blur');
        };
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">   
    <div id="msg">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle which replicates your problem?

Comment: Try to register _focus_ and _blur_ events for _document.body_ instead of _window_.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko http://jsfiddle.net/e2XBt/

Comment: @AndrewD. tried doing that still the same issue

Comment: @AshokD, using that jsfiddle, I only get one message at a time.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko have you tried on IE8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally it got solved. Thank you for all the help!

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
        pageLoad();
    });

    var activeElement;

    function pageLoad() {
        activeElement = document.activeElement;
        document.onfocusout = logWindow;
    }

    function logWindow() {
        if (activeElement != document.activeElement) {
            activeElement = document.activeElement;
        }
        else {
            $('#msg').html($('#msg').html()+'<br/> Focus');
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is this doing? Please explain.

Comment: @dhinesh IE has issue with window.onblur event. Hence above is the workaround.

At window load we are registering document.onfocusout event and setting the document as activeElemnt.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
This event bubbles out which is not the case of window.onblur. When any control lost's its focus document's onfocusout event gets fired.

Comment: +1 - Epic, worked for me when $(window).blur was failing in ie8.

Answer (score 1):

```
 window.onblur = function() { 
      $('#msg').html($('#msg').html() + '<br/> Blur');     
      return false;
 };
```

May be the event is getting bubbled up.

Comment: still getting the same issue.